Due to the Python GIL, access to "most" variables is (usually said to be) thread safe. However access to global variables is not. What explains this?
There are several questions on Stack Overflow which explain why access to global variables is not thread safe in Python, even with the presence of the Global Interpreter Lock.
This reason for this is that the GIL only permits a single Python Interpreter instance to execute bytecode at any one time. However, since many operations on data in memory consist of several byte code operations (they are not atomic), if two threads switch such that one stops running and another resumes, this might take place while the state in memory and the state of the interpreter are not aligned at a synchronization point. (Think "race condition".)
If the above statement isn't immediatly clear, there are some good explanations available on this site. Here is one such example.
However, in direct contradiction to this, it is often stated that the purpose of the GIL is to simplify multi-thread programming by preventing race conditions. Here is one such example. (but it this may be - and seems to me to be - a common misconception or misunderstanding)
However, this is not a sufficiently detailed explanation, since while global variables are not protected from race conditions, for the reasons described above, some variables are, and this is frequently stated as common lore.
So - why is access to "not global" ("some") variables guaranteed to be thread safe? Or yet better, under what conditions is access to a variable guaranteed to be thread safe?
One relatively easy to understand example is that of local variables: Since each function call has its own independent stack frame and set of local variables, clearly one thread cannot create a race condition with another in the context of local variables which have a lifetime which is confined to that of a function call.
Put another way, if multiple threads are dispatched with an entry point of my_function any variables created during the lifetime of this function call are independent of all other threads running in parallel.
As an extension to this idea, if a reference to a (local or otherwise) variable is passed into multiple functions which execute concurrently, this would not be guaranteed to be thread safe, because two or more threads are holding a reference to the same object in memory. (This is essentially very similar to that of the global variable example.)
Are there any other examples? Or do these two examples sufficiently explain the set of possibilities that must be considered?

The GIL is there to make things easier on the people writing the interpreter itself, not people writing Python programs. It does not make access to "most" variables thread-safe.

The GIL is not intended to provide any thread safety for your Python code. It only is meant to provide thread safety for the Python implementation's own code. The GIL may have a few subtle benefits that make writing multi-threaded Python code slightly more relaxed than in other languages, but there's a reason why they provided you with the threading.Lock class. You're probably going to need it if you're going to write any kind of serious, multi-threaded code.

Sure, I am asking this from the context of someone who is familiar with mutexes and locks but not familiar with the internal implementation of Python. It is likely the case that many of the things I have read about GIL and thread safety are misconceptions, because in many cases I don't doubt that the people who wrote the articles which I have read also do not have an in depth or detailed understanding of how Python is implemented and what the GIL does/does not do.

So, what does the GIL help with when implementing the Python interpreter? Is is just there to simplify the garbage collector implementation, for example?

I believe you are overcomplicating situations that actually are quite intuitive.
If one resource is referenced by code that might be running concurrently (be it in another thread, another async task, or even a managed object with multiprocessing), any modifications onto that resource have to be guarded with an apropriated lock. (There are different locks in the language for each of this).
One doesn´t have any guarrantees in the language of any atomic operation, because it doesn´t and can´t matter, how many bytecode instructions a given operation takes to execute - even the += operator for integers is not threadsafe (because the old value is read, a new value is computed, and assigned to the old name).
What you are calling "thread safety" in your text are just simple isolated contexts other concurrent code won´t affect - as I said, that can be quite intuitive. For any mutable resource that is shared across concurrent code, there is "thread unsafety", unless explicit means to ensure a transaction isolation are used. (Just note that in the case of async programming, just avoiding any await, async for and async with  statement ensures that your code is the only one operating on the given values at any one moment - an explicit lock is seldon needed)
Comming to the GIL, as well put in the comments: it makes the implementation of the Python runtime itself easier.
Things like operations into built-in data-types, such as appending to lists, or creating new keys in a dictionary, are the kind of thing that are naturally thread-safe in Python. (But if you need to read a value from these structures, operate on it, and write it back, you simply have to use a proper lock)

Why are those particular operations you describe inherently thread safe? I would imagine, for example, that appending to a list requires a long sequence of bytecode to execute. (It would be highly surprising if this were not the case.) What about the workings of the GIL ensure this is thread safe?

It is likely a single bytecode - but that does not matter, as I said - what matters is that the kind of thread safity that is ready made in Python is this: operations provided by methods (special, like __setitem__l or otherwise, like .append )  are threadsafe: appending to a list will grow it, if needed, change its intermal lenght attribute, and write the new value to the end in a thread-safe operation, due to the GIL.

python bytecodes are not the same as Java bytecodes: while I can imagine an structure like a Python list in Java would use JVM opcodes to perform the very basic ops (check reserved length, reallocate memory, etc...) , Python VM bytecode is very high level, and the lower level ops run in native code (written in C in CPython)

And, comming to a "GILess" Python that will be an option in version 3.13: developers are finding performant ways around it, so even the builds without GIL sure will keep the same warranties that operations in the built-in data structures will continue to be thread safe.  From the PoV of a Python developer, nothing will change but that a multithreaded Python process will be able to make use of all CPU cores. It is extensions developers (Python projects using native code) which will change somewhat significativelly.

Right - I'm somewhat reading between the lines here but I would imagine in this case that the byte codes for certain operations are essentially guaranteed to be "effectively atomic" meaning the interpreter cannot switch threads while it is in the process of executing those bytecode ops. Is that somewhat along the right lines?

As I stated above: one better not to worry about bytecode count - they are mostly an implementation detail (the latest Python versions evenuse some sort of adaptative self-specialising bytecode at runtime). Rather, there are some operations that are inherently thread-safe in the language, and this safety is guaranteed, up to Python3.12, by the GIL. For Python 3.13 onwards, other mechanisms are used for the same guarantee (check https://peps.python.org/pep-0703/ for details)

which operations are "thread safe", yes, is the important part: any operation in a built-in data structure such as list, dict, set, bytearrays. Note that the language allows one to replicate the functionality of structures in pure-Python code, such as collection.UserDict): such classes won't be threadsafe to use by default - the author has to explicitly code-in thread Locks to ensure that.
